# how can i find memory leakage in node.js when using bull-Queue

Tags: node.js, debugging, cron, bull, bull-queue

I am running a bull que with cronJob and I am going a parallel of 5000 parallel jobs. Which caused, stuck/breakage for my entire bull job not running...

So I tried chrome inspect through node --inspect-brk app.js & node --inspect app. js

And using chrome → chrome://inspect/#devices

I have recieved received around 300+mb usage, but how can I go ahead with the debugging process??

I am looking forward to the debugging process.